# Usar variable php como clase

Tags: php, html, css

estoy intentando que un div html coja como clase una variable php, como puedo resolver esto, muchas gracias.

```
<?php if ($comp[0]=="Llama League"):
    $class2="fortnite";
elseif ($comp[0]=="Energy Fruit CR"):
    $class2="clash"; 
else:
    $class1="esport";
endif;
?><div class=\"$class2\">
```

Comment: Puedes hacer un `echo` dentro del bloque PHP, como te indiqué en la otra pregunta. Así evitas mezclar tanto código PHP/HTML, es una mezcla poco estética y además produce un código difícil de leer, depurar, analizar. No sé si tu código es parte de un curso. Como veo que haces muchas evaluaciones de este tipo, en vez de `elseif` yo pasaría a otro modelo: evaluando a través de un array. Es útil sobre todo cuando son varias condiciones, supongamos que en vez de tres posibilidades hay 10, 15, 30 ... en vez de 30 `elseif` puedes poner los valores en un array y buscarlos por su índice.

Comment: Ya lo que pasa que ese div encierra un bloque con más div dentro por eso no he usado la forma que me dijiste anteriormente.Muchas gracias.

Comment: Aunque sea así puedes usar esa forma. Luego del `echo` cierras el bloque PHP con `?>` y sigues con el resto del contenido HTML  No tiene gran importancia, funciona de las dos maneras pero a mí me gusta en la medida de lo posible evitar la mezcla constante de PHP/HTML incluso para hacer un simple `echo` de una variable.

Comment: Pero para cerrar del div al final de todo el codigo sirve hacerlo con echo?

Comment: Sirve cualquiera de los dos, según te convenga.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya que tu `div` está fuera de tu sentencia PHP debes hacer un `echo` de tu variable.

```
<?php
    if ($comp[0] == "Llama League"):
        $class2 = "fortnite";
    elseif ($comp[0] == "Energy Fruit CR"):
        $class2 = "clash"; 
    else:
        $class1 = "esport";
    endif;
?>
<div class="<?php echo $class2 ?>">
```

Comment: Aníbal, en vez de abrir cerrar bloques de PHP, lo cual hace el código más difícil de leer y analizar, puede poner el echo dentro del bloque anterior simplemente: `echo "<div class=\"$class2\">";` Así, todo queda dentro de un mismo bloque PHP.